# and_call_original used with allow_any_instance_of is not working after rspec upgrade to 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I had a code in rspec 2.14.1 like

```
allow_any_instance_of(AnyClass).to receive(:some_method).and_call_original
```

with a corresponding message expectation

```
expect_any_instance_of(AnyClass).to receive(:some_method)
```

The above worked fine in rspec 2.14.1. After upgrade to rspec 3.1.0, the above code no longer works. It fails on the message expectation that some_method is not called even once

However if I change the stub like

```
allow_any_instance_of(AnyClass).to receive(:some_method).and_return(value)
```

it works fine in rspec 3.1.0.

I just wanted to understand why using and_call_original with allow_any_instance_of fails after rspec upgrade.

I can see from [this link](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation) that `and_call_original` is only supported on partial doubles.

Does that mean using `allow_any_instance_of` is not partial double?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`and_call_original` does actually work when used with `allow_any_instance_of`.

Refer the specs for `any_instance` which gives us an idea of different ways of mocking or to un-stub using `and_call_original` [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/spec/rspec/mocks/any_instance_spec.rb).

To answer my question above, the way I was using message expectation is wrong. It should be:

```
allow_any_instance_of(AnyClass).to(
  receive(:any_method).and_call_original
)
expect(AnyClass.new.any_method).to eq(:any_method_value)
```

I was trying to use `expect_any_instance_of` instead of expect which caused the issue.